# php mysql for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

in my query i want only from id 1-3 to appear in the result, not 4-6.  is there any other way to do it?

```
beautician database table:
id_beautician   name
1               a
2               b
3               c
4               d
5               e
6               f
```

i tried to put the code below in mysql query

```
for($i=4; $i<=6; $i++) :
    $q.$i = $db->query("SELECT * FROM beautician WHERE id_beautician='$i'");
    $r.$i = $q.$i->fetch_assoc();
    //echo $i;
endfor;
```

but it gives me an error:

> Object of class mysqli_result could
>   not be converted to string

Comment: WHERE id_beautician in (4,5,6)

Comment: PLEASE use `$db->real_escape_string` or at least cast the id to (int). Learn about SQL injection!

Comment: @cweiske: of cuz .. ive got everything set up. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ids are not in sequence, you can also use as below.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM beautician WHERE id_beautician in (1,2,3)");
while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) 
{
    echo $row['id'] . ' = ' . $row['name'] . '<br/>';
}
```

using IN in query sometimes slow down the execution, but can be used efficiently for small-size database.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing `n` queries, modify SQL query to match only data you need - for example:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM beautician WHERE id_beautician <= 3");
while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo $row['id'] . ' = ' . $row['name'] . '<br/>';
}
```